# How to track untracked files in node_modules w/ contains emphasized items

Tags: reactjs, git

[t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAiUI.png)
Hello,

I'm creating a react template from scratch in visual studio code, and in the node_modules folder there is a .bin folder which contains untracked files. The green dot means that files that are untracked contains emphasized items. I am trying to track those files so I can add node_modules to .gitignore. How can I track files in node_modules so they are ready to be add to .gitignore?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAiUI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Files do not need to be tracked to be ignored. Once you commit the .gitignore file VSCode should pick up on it and change the highlighting.